# Parse filename for label Xcode

Tags: parsing, xcode7, filenames

The code below returns weather data.  All works fine except for the current weather description.  For example, if todaysimage file name is `partlycloudyv3.png`.  The description shows as `partlycloudy` in my app.  How can I make it appear as `partly cloudy`?

```
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  if (self) {
    NSArray *theView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HipSkin01" owner:self options:nil];
    UIView *nv = [theView objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePathDocArray = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"r.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePathDocArray]) {
        NSLog(@"The file exists");
        dataz = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]   initWithContentsOfFile:filePathDocArray];

        NSLog(@"The file exists %@",dataz);
        NSLog(@"The array: %i",(int) [dataz count]);

    }

    NSString *todaysimage = [dataz valueForKey:@"icon"];
    [self.weatherIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@v3.png", todaysimage]]];

    NSArray *arr1 = [dataz objectForKey:@"display_location"];
    NSString *plasez = [arr1 valueForKey:@"full"];
    //NSString *plasez = [arr1 valueForKey:@"city"];
    [self.plase setText:plasez];


    //DataFormater
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, YYYY"];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [self.dataLable setText:dateToday];
    [self.nameWeather setText:todaysimage];


    //temp

    NSString *tempzC = [dataz valueForKey:@"feelslike_c"];
    NSString *tempzF = [dataz valueForKey:@"feelslike_f"];

    NSString *terC = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°C",tempzC];
    NSString *terF = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@°F",tempzF];

    [self.temprC setText:terC];
    [self.temprF setText:terF];

    [self addSubview:nv];
}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added these lines and the parsing issue was solved.  I was referencing the incorrect item in the weather API.

```
    NSString *todaysimage2 = [dataz valueForKey:@"weather"];

    [self.weatherIcons setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@v3.png", todaysimage]]];

    [self.weatherData setText:dateToday];

    [self.weatherText setText:todaysimage2];
```